# ASP.NET: can a button in an UpdatePanel cause a postback?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

I use UpdatePanels in a ModalPopupExtender and it works well (allowing parts of the dialog box to be refreshed when some controls are clicked, while avoiding full postbacks), but there is one small thing that is not exactly what I would like.

The OK button is disabled by default and enabled when changes are made in the dialog box, so the button is in an UpdatePanel. However, I would like a click on the OK button to cause a full postback. Is there a "natural" way to achieve that behavior?

N.B. Avoiding full postbacks is not only a matter of esthetics: they cause the dialog box to disappear from the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If the dialog disappears from the screen, just make it appear again when the full postback completes.

```
if(DialogShouldBeVisible)
{
    mpe.Show();
}
```

Anyways, to cause a full postback you just register it as a regular [`PostBackTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <PostBackTrigger ControlId="OkBtn">
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button runat="server" id="OkBtn" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

By the way, I recommend against using UpdatePanel and ModalPopupExtender and anything else from the Ajax Control Toolkit. They don't fit in well with other easily customizable client side stuff. Instead, use [dialog from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or some other well supported client side framework, and use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to pass data to the server. It's much easier to put together a nice site that way.

Comment: mason - Thanks for the suggestions about other alternatives. I will look at them and see if they make my life easier. It's a good time to try them: I am refactoring my whole Web application, following the decision by Google to drop the showModalDialog function in Chrome.